# What is the access modifier of an anonymous class's constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, anonymous-class

**NOTE:** This is a self-answered question. It may be a very simple one but I thought it would be worth sharing.

Suppose I have an anonymous class declaration:

```
MyObject myObj1 = new MyObject() {

};
```

where `MyObject` is:

```
class MyObject {

    public MyObject() { // explicit public constructor
    }

    ...
}
```

From [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) of the Java Language Specification (emphasis mine):

> An anonymous class cannot have an explicitly declared constructor. Instead, an **anonymous constructor** is implicitly declared for an anonymous class.

If I try to get the number of `public` constructors:

```
// Number of public constructors; prints 0
System.out.println(myObj1.getClass().getConstructors().length);
```

it prints zero as expected, i.e. the anonymous constructor is not `public`.

It is also not `private`, since if we call the following from a different class in the same package where the anonymous class is defined (by passing around the instance `myObj1`):

```
myObj1.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

it completes **without** an `IllegalAccessException`.

What is the access modifier of the implicit constructor in an anonymous class?

Comment: What led you to perform this investigation?

Comment: @dnault I was just wondering about the (conceptual) use of an anonymous class as a singleton and thought about the constructor.

Comment: What difference does it make? You can't call it.

Comment: @EJP The question that triggered this question dealt with reflection. In real life, yes I won't need to call it.

Answer (score 9):

The anonymous constructor acts similar to the [default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) that the compiler also creates for a normal class that does not declare constructors. In this case:

> In a class type, if the class is declared `public`, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier `public` (§6.6); if the class is declared `protected`, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier `protected` (§6.6); if the class is declared `private`, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier `private` (§6.6); **otherwise, the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier**.

In other words, the anonymous constructor is only accessible in the same package as the anonymous class.